# Sublime text creating new view

Tags: python, sublimetext2

Just taking a look at Sublime Text 2 with a view to extending it.  I've popped up the console with CTRL ', and tried to do:

```
>>> x = window.new_file()
>>> x 
<sublime.View object at 0x00000000032EBA70>
>>> x.insert(0,"Hello")
```

A new window does indeed open but my insert seemingly doesn't work:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<string>", line 1, in <module> Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
        View.insert(View, int, str) did not match C++ signature:
        insert(class SP<class TextBufferView>, class SP<class Edit>, __int64, class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> >)
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `.new_file()` call returned a `View` object, so the `.insert()` method takes *3* arguments:

> `insert(edit, point, string)`
>   `int`
>   Inserts the given `string` in the buffer at the specified `point`. Returns the number of characters inserted: this may be different if tabs are being translated into spaces in the current buffer.

See the [`sublime.View` API reference](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/api_reference.html#sublime.View).

The `edit` parameter is meant to be a [`sublime.Edit`](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/api_reference.html#sublime.Edit) object; you need to call `view.begin_edit()` to create one, then call `view.end_edit(edit)` to demarque a undoable edit:

```
edit = x.begin_edit() 
x.insert(edit, 0, 'Hello')
x.end_edit(edit)
```

The `Edit` object is a token to group edits into something that can be undone in one step.

Comment: @DaveF: `edit` is a *parameter*, of type [`sublime.Edit`](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/api_reference.html#sublime.Edit). Use `view.begin_edit()` to create one.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> x = window.new_file()
>>> e = x.begin_edit()
>>> x.insert(e,0,"Hello")
5
>>> x.end_edit(e)
```